# Is there any way to scroll to a particular child in react sortable tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app.js component

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import SortableTree from 'react-sortable-tree';
import 'react-sortable-tree/style.css';
import './App.css';




class App extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      treeData: [{
        title: 'Chicken',
        children: [{
          title: 'Egg1'
        },{
          title: 'Egg2'
        },{
          title: 'Egg3'
        },{
          title: 'Egg4'
        },{
          title: 'Egg5'
        },{
          title: 'Egg6'
        },{
          title: 'Egg7'
        },{
          title: 'Egg8'
        },{
          title: 'Egg9'
        },{
          title: 'Egg10'
        },{
          title: 'Egg11'
        },{
          title: 'Egg12'
        },{
          title: 'Egg13'
        },{
          title: 'Egg14'
        },{
          title: 'Egg15'
        },{
          title: 'Egg16'
        },{
          title: 'Egg17'
        }]
      }] 
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 400 }}>
        <SortableTree
          treeData={this.state.treeData}
          onChange={treeData => this.setState({ treeData })}
          generateNodeProps={clickedNode => ({
            className:clickedNode.node.title,
            id:clickedNode.node.title
          })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

>
```

---

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: added what ever i have tried so far

Answer (score 3):

Yeah if you assign an `id` to that element then we can do something like this -:

```
var element = document.getElementById("child");
element.scrollIntoView();
```

here is a working demo...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pz9mmu

Comment: document.getElementById("child") is giving null if the element is not visible

Comment: @Akhil Please add the full code...... I need to see the full code in order to debug..

Comment: the above code is what i have tried so far.

i am not able to get the id of last element if it is not visible in screen its giving as null

Comment: @Akhil I have a working demo you can refer to this -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pz9mmu

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i am using react sortable tree for the tree view.There i am facing this issue

Comment: @Akhil then in that case I need your whole react-sortable integrated code to proceed with this issue.

Comment: the same code is shared above please do click on edit and take the code as it is not showing properly in view mode
(app.js file is shared above,the react-sortable-tree package you can install)

Comment: @Akhil I don't understand, i can;'t see anything after clicking edit. Can you please share the minimal working code on the same stackblitz link above....

Comment: Or we can get on private chat and finish this bug

Comment: can't able to update the code in stackblitz. please change the privacy settings

Comment: Pretty sure, as @Akhil mentions, this won't work if the element is far down the tree (because it is not rendered in the DOM yet until scrolled into view)

Answer (score 1):

react-sortable-tree with version 2.3.0 has a property called "searchQuery" which will scroll to matched node and highlight the node (use unique value for title or subtitle as it use title or subtitle property for searching matches)